# UNION two tables in a subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, union

I am trying to `UNION` two tables in a subquery, but apparently this is not allowed? A simplified version of my query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM user, organization
WHERE user.id NOT IN (
    (SELECT distinct user_id FROM web_request)
    UNION
    (SELECT distinct user_id from user_milestone)
)
AND user.organization_id = organization.id
```

My question is this: What is the best way to get around this shortcoming of MySQL?

Comment: Parens don't matter.

Comment: @RyanVincent No worries.

Comment: what is an error ?

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad The very not useful `1064: You have an error in your SQL Syntax .... near 'UNION'`.

Comment: @RyanVincent Yeah, I think you're right. If you want to submit an answer...

Comment: @RyanVincent What is the purpose of deleting comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT u.*, o.*
FROM `user` u
INNER JOIN organization o
ON u.organization_id = o.id
WHERE u.id NOT IN(
    SELECT distinct user_id FROM web_request
    UNION
    SELECT distinct user_id from user_milestone
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM   USER u
JOIN   organization o
ON     u.organization_id = o.id
WHERE  u.uid NOT IN SELECT  * (
       (
            SELECT DISTINCT user_id
            FROM            web_request )
union
      (
            SELECT DISTINCT user_id
            FROM            user_milestone) ) AS t
```

Comment: I think `WHERE  u.uid NOT IN SELECT  * (` should be `WHERE  u.uid NOT IN SELECT  * from (` but the answer is very helpful indeed.