# Error using union subquery inside in statement

Tags: mysql

I'm tyring to use a where clause with a subquery inside a 'in'statement.

Thisis my query:

```
select *
from trading.historical_prices

where
date in (

        (select date
        from trading.historical_prices
        group by date
        order by date desc
        limit 1) 

        union 
        (
        select date
        from trading.historical_prices
        group by date
        order by date desc
        limit 7,1
        ) 


)

limit 100
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'union 
        (
        select date
        from trading.historical_prices
        group by date
        orde' at line 13
```

The union query works fine when it's ran alone.
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37598964/union-two-tables-in-a-subquery), you don't parenthesis.

So your query would look like so :

```
SELECT * 
FROM   trading.historical_prices 
WHERE  date IN 
       ( 
                SELECT   date 
                FROM     trading.historical_prices 
                GROUP BY date 
                ORDER BY date DESC limit 1 
                UNION 
                SELECT   date 
                FROM     trading.historical_prices 
                GROUP BY date 
                ORDER BY date DESC limit 7, 
                         1) limit 100
```

Comment: Parenthesis are compulsary for mysql version >=5.7. Though it should not be an issue here.

Comment: Look at this SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/11906, when using parenthesis I had the same error as he did, when not, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/11907, I have another type of error.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: The ORDER BY error appeared after removing the parenthesis?